# Html code line turn green in dreamweaver

Tags: html, dreamweaver

Just a simple question. What does it mean when a html code line turn green in dreamweaver?
Example; `<div class="container">` for some reason gets a green font color.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just noticed this 'error' myself and looks like if the html code is embedded with php it will give a false positive.

e.g.

I have a info panel next to a registration form which I hide and display an error message if an error is detected after submit, ie if that person has previously registered.

In the div tag I have < ?php if ($error==1) echo ('style="display:none"')?> which produces the green code on the rest of the text display.

Hope this helps.